# How to short or hide the git repository's absolute path by ssh protocol?

Tags: git

I am building a git server on Ubuntu.

On the git server, I create a git repository on /opt/var/git/example.git.
When a client wants to clone this git repository, he should use the command "git clone ssh://username@host-ip/opt/var/git/example.git"

I wonder if there is any way to short the ssh path and hide the absolute path.

For example, the client could clone "example.git" by 
"git clone ssh://username@host-ip/example.git".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the users's home directory to where the git repository is.

Or you can just symlink the repo into the users home directory with `ln -s /path/to/repo ~/reponame.git`

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to add an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [**gitolite**](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which:

- will control who can clone what
- always use short addresses for the git repositories

  git clone git@host:arepo

(no need for the `.git` at then end)

Comment: Alternatively, use the `--base-path` option to `git daemon` which will decide what is exposed.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim true. I just like all the fine-grained control options which are coming with `gitolite`. But `git daemon` is part of git, `gitolite` isn't, so point taken.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim "--base-path" is **just** for git protocol not for ssh protocol.

Comment: @HaifengLi you could use `ssh+git://` addresses, but the git protocol is mainly used for ead-only access anyway, not pushes since they are anonymous.